# Align Navigation bar with Logo or Website name

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

I am creating a code portfolio website focused more on game and app development. It has been a while since I have done HTML and I can't figure out how to align a header with the navigation bar. I am unsure if I need to use two separate div's or if I can do it using CSS.

For example, I want it to have this effect:

```
Youtube Channel          |-----------------------------------| Represents
Name                     |-----------------------------------| Nav. Bar
```

The nav. the bar should be centered between the two lines of text

This is the code I am working with:

In the head under :

```
ul {
 margin-left: 150px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
.name {
 color: black;
}
```

ul will control the entire un-ordered list and .name controls the the header 3

In the body:

```
<h3 class="name">
Intentionally left blank. Refer to example text
</h3>
<ul>
UN-ordered list for links to other pages. Intentionally not adding the lines because there are a lot of un-needed lines of code here.
</ul>
```

When I run it the output is:

```
YouTube Channel
Name
                  |----------------------------| Represents
                  |----------------------------| Nav. Bar
```

And my desired output is:

```
Youtube Channel          |-----------------------------------| Represents
Name                     |-----------------------------------| Nav. Bar
```

Comment: Just use `display: inline-block` or `float: left` -- setting a `margin-left` of `150px` will have a negative effect on small devices.

Comment: Doing just that still creates the undesired effect, just on top of each other. Hopefully, this combined with flexbox will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be like this

```css
ul {
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
.name {
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; width:80%">
<h3 class="name">YouTube Channel</h3>
<h3 class="name">Name</h3>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width:20%">
<ul>Represents</ul>
<ul>Nav. Bar</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I essentially did that but within the style header. Can't believe I didn't think of that and helps as a quick simple fix. Going to check out flexbox still but going to use this for now.